# How Can I Override Visual Studio's Menu Accelerator Shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, menu, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I'm a Mac-based .Net developer so over the years I've got into the habit of remapping certain common functions to a more 'Macish' set of keyboard shortcuts:

```
CUT: Ctrl + X => Alt + X
COPY: Ctrl + C => Alt + C
PASTE: Ctrl + V => Alt + V
SELECT ALL: Ctrol + A => Alt + A
SAVE: Ctrl + S => Alt + S
```

and so on.

with this fancy schmancy VS 2010 Premium edition we've just got we've got extra menus e.g.

```
 Test
 Data
```

whose menu accessor (accelerator?)shortcuts are `Alt + S` and `Alt + A` which take precedence over my user-defined shortcuts for `SAVE` and `SELECT ALL`.

Is there a way of disabling these accessors so my overrides will work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's how to change the shortcut key for a Visual Studio menu, using the 'Test' menu as an example:

1. Go to **Tools**, **Customize**.
2. Click the **Commands** tab.
3. Ensure the **`Menu bar`** option is selected, and that **`Menu Bar`** is chosen for editing from the drop-down (this is the primary application menu bar).
4. In the **Controls** section, click on the **`Test`** menu.
5. Click on the **Modify Selection ▼** button.
6. Change the text for the **`Name`** property:

   - Any letter prefixed with an '`&`' ampersand will act as the shortcut key.
   - The ampersand is not required if you don't need to reach this menu with the keyboard.
7. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to keep the setting.

> [image: Editing the Test menu]
>
> **'Modify Selection' for the Test menu**

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very, very much indeed. Please have 50 points with my blessing and eternal gratitude  ;-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in VS 22...  Whenever alt is pressed the control menu is selected and if you press a combo that doesn't bind,  VS chimes at you overriding any other shortcuts you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this something the fault of the Windows API, not Visual Studio?  I think the Alt (and nothing else) keyboard shortcuts are directed through Windows API, so the OS will probably not let you do this; it'll select the menu with the respective mnemonic (underlined letter).

You could try using a custom keyboard layout that would swap the left ctrl and left alt keys, allowing you to use "ctrl-S" but it feels like command-S.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -2):

go to tools -options - keyboard(you may have to choose show all option or something like that to be able to see this one) and you can change the shortcuts

Comment: The shortcuts I've set in Tools > Keyboard are fine. The issue is that the VS menu accessor shortcuts are taking precedence over them. Try setting a shortcut with `Alt+S` and you'll see that this keypress will bring down the `Test` menu...