# Disable menu bar shortcuts in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm using the Emacs plugin for Visual Studio 2010, and I'd like to liberate my meta key.

When I press `Alt-foo`, I activate drop-downs on the menu bar instead of lovely Emacs commands. For example, I open the analyze menu when I try to move forward by one word, since both commands are invoked with `Alt-N`.

How do I disable the menu bar `Alt-` shortcuts and fully appreciate my Emacs environment?

Comment: Don't know if you can disable, but you can override: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990483/how-can-i-override-visual-studios-menu-accelerator-shortcuts

Comment: Thank you! The first answer actually shows how to disable alt-shortcuts per menu item, which is good enough for me!